# Vue - Is there a way to scope $refs on a form

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am passing in `props` to my form. So the data in the form can be populated from these `props` or from user entry. Because I'm using `props` I don't have `data` defined for these elements. But instead am using `v-model` and passing in my `props`.

The problem then is when I want to submit, how can I get all the form data.

I realized I can define `refs` on the form inputs in order to grab the data from the form in order to submit it. But with that solution I have to step thru each data element individually. What I would like to do is just step thru the `form` and pull the data out in a `forEach` loop.

Is that possible?

[Here is my code running.](https://bc-only-rates-trimakas.c9users.io)

And this is the top of my template (using Vuetify as a framework) with one of the elements of my form:

```
<template>
<v-container fluid grid-list-lg class="come_closer">
  <v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex xs12 v-for="(creds, index) in amazonCredsArray" :key="creds.id" class="pb-4">
      <v-card class="lightpurple">
        <v-card-title>
          <v-icon class="my_dark_purple_text">language</v-icon>
          <h1 class="title oswald my_dark_purple_text pl-2 pr-5">ENTER YOUR CREDENTIALS BELOW</h1>
        </v-card-title>

     <v-form ref="form" lazy-validation>
        <v-layout xs12 row wrap class="mx-auto" >
          <v-flex xs12>
            <v-text-field
              ref="seller_id"
              :rules="[ v => sellerIdRules(v, index) ]"
              validate-on-blur
              required
              color="indigo"
              label="Amazon Seller Id"
              v-model="creds.seller_id"
              prepend-icon="person"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-flex>
```

Then on submit I would have to run a method for each element that contains this:

```
this.$refs.seller_id.forEach(function(element){console.log(element.value)});
```

Is there an easier way to do this? Can I scope my `refs` so I can just use 1 `forEach` loop. Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this problem.

The simplest is probably to create data properties that should hold the state of your input fields and initialize them with props.

```
props: ['value'],

data () {
   return {
      valueLocal: this.value
   }
}
```

Now, data properties can be used to reflect the value of your input fields again:

```
<input v-model="valueLocal">
```

Downside is, if the prop value changes after the component is mounted, those changes are ignored by your component.

You can however, extend the component definition with watchers. This way `valueLocal` is always equal to whatever changed last. The prop or the user input.

```
props: ['value'],

data () {
   return {
      valueLocal: this.value
   }
},

watch: {
    value (newValue) {
        this.valueLocal = newValue
    }
}
```

Note, that `v-model` is basically just syntax sugar for binding the `value` attribute and listening for the `input` event. So `v-model` is just short for:

```
<input :value="valueLocal" @input="valueLocal = $event.target.value">
```

So you might as well keep your form component generic and let the parent component handle the state.

#### Form component

The template of your form component:

```
<input :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
<!-- ... --->
<input type="submit" @submit="$emit('submit')">
```

No data properties required, only props:

```
props: ['value']
```

#### Parent component

In the parent component template:

```
<form-component :value="value" @input="value = $event" @submit="...">
```

Or use `v-model` again

```
<form-component v-model="value" @submit="...">
```

Since you have multiple input elements in your form component this is less of an option though.

Comment: but how would you do something like `$refs.element.focus()`? you can't control that with a state

Comment: You mean because focus is a programmatic action right? But changing text content of an input field is also a programmatic action. Vue just abstracts that away. You can do the same with focus. Check out: https://shorturl.at/rtwBI

Comment: thanks. i am a bit confused with the syntax, because i am using petite vue, but i think i understand what you mean